# Asp net core Blazor Auth0 Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, auth0, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor Server side and Auth0 to deal with logins to my app.

I get to the login screen fine but when I click OK to login with correct credentials I get this:

```
Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

Works fine localhost but not when running in my Beanstalk AWS environment.

I have added all relevant callback URL's inside Auth0 dashboard.

My Startup.cs has this for the callback which I believe shouldn't be an issue.

```
// Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
// Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");
```

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue you need to ensure you have end-to-end SSL from load balancer all the way through to your instances. Otherwise, the HTTPS request gets converted to HTTP (for the callback) and fails.